# Is it possible to avoid quadratic compile times in Rust when using large expressions (8k lines taking one hour to compile)?

Tags: rust

## Background

I have a code generator which can produce long expressions within rust, but the compiler seems to not handle this well.  In these examples I am using constants/addition for simplicity, but in practice I would like to support more complicated expressions involving variables and other programming constructs.

## Example

```
fn main() {
  let _x = 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
// ...
// 500 identical lines
// ...
+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
;
}
```

When I try to compile this it crashes `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. (It works with fewer lines in the middle so I think it is just a crash caused by the length of the expression.)

## What I've tried

### Extra brackets

I've tried putting in brackets in various places.  Adding brackets to the start and end of each line stops the crash but takes one hour to compile (and also changes the semantics as the order of operations is different):

```
fn main() {
  let _x = 1+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
// ...
// 8000 identical lines
// ...
+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)
;
}
```

### fasteval

[fasteval](https://docs.rs/fasteval/latest/fasteval/index.html) looks like it would handle expressions much faster, but only of basic variable manipulation and function calls, so would not handle a mix of expressions and more complicated rust code.

### Variables

Breaking each expression into lots of generated variables (one for each binary operator) also stops the crash, but still has quadratic compile time in the number of variables (e.g. 9 seconds for adding 8000 numbers, and 37 seconds for adding 16000 numbers).

### Decomposing expressions into multiple functions

This feels like it should work, but is quite a lot more work in the code generation.

### Changing the compiler

Looking into the rust compiler source code, it looks like the slowness might be coming from a lot of cloning of the abstract syntax nodes when tree manipulations are made.  It feels like a lot of the time the underlying data is immutable so it may be possible to reuse references to existing immutable data rather than copying all the tree.  However, this feels like it might take quite a lot of effort to get working.

## Question

Are there any other ways of avoiding the slow compile time of large expressions in rust?  (This is my first rust program so I have probably missed something obvious like a compiler flag or a more idiomatic way of writing expressions)

### Update

Example profile output of the compiler.

```
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Item                                            | Self time | % of total time | Time     | Item count |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| typeck                                          | 4.99s     | 69.503          | 4.99s    | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| thir_body                                       | 1.73s     | 24.112          | 1.73s    | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| mir_built                                       | 328.48ms  | 4.572           | 2.06s    | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| run_linker                                      | 50.88ms   | 0.708           | 50.88ms  | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
...
```

[image: Profile]

### Change to use brackets and i32

As suggested in an answer below by Chayim Friedman, the typeck time can be avoided by using 1i32 instead.  The profile now spends most time in thir_body (profile from 3k line file):

```
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| Item                                            | Self time | % of total time | Time     | Item count |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| thir_body                                       | 6.49s     | 73.044          | 6.49s    | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| mir_built                                       | 1.02s     | 11.506          | 7.51s    | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| mir_borrowck                                    | 402.33ms  | 4.529           | 7.93s    | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| mir_drops_elaborated_and_const_checked          | 394.76ms  | 4.444           | 394.80ms | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| typeck                                          | 306.75ms  | 3.453           | 312.72ms | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| optimized_mir                                   | 118.45ms  | 1.333           | 513.32ms | 5          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
| run_linker                                      | 52.22ms   | 0.588           | 52.22ms  | 1          |
+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: try compile with bigger stack, I don't really know what to do on this question, on one hand you give some detail but on other it's unclear what you are really doing so it's hard to advice how to do better if we don't know what you are doing. And fix compiler limitation is...

Comment: It is for backend for a hardware description language.  You describe the hardware in this language (e.g. for a hardware video encoder), and the code generator produces rust code that simulates the hardware. When the hardware involves a lot of parallelism, you can end up with large functions representing the code to be run.

Comment: Probably the best solution will be to generate the Rust code in a different way, so that you don't get such large expressions. For example, `let x = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 ...;` could be replaced with `let mut x = 0; x += 1; x += 1; x += 1; ...`

Comment: Thanks, using the mutable variables does help a lot!  16000 adds now take 7 seconds, 32k adds take 28 seconds. So it seems this gives a good acceleration, but is still quadratic compile time.

Comment: [Profile the compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/measureme/blob/master/summarize/README.md) and tell us where time is spent. Also, this looks worth reporting a bug (if there isn't one already).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I've added the profile as requested.

Comment: The compiler overflows the stack as it is visiting the AST and it is too deep. It has protections against stack overflows (stack segments) in later stages - from HIR on if I remember correctly - but not in the AST. If you want to change the compiler to avoid stack overflow, this is pretty simple (but I won't recommend). Using parens is a good alternative, though. If you can't (for order of computation reasons) use variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `1` is not a fixed type, it is an inference variable that can be any integer type. To determine that it is `i32`, the compiler has to go through all combinations of `Add` impl, and fall back to the fallback type `i32`.

Use suffixed integers (`1i32`) and this will compile much faster.

Comment: Thanks, yes suffixed integers helps enormously!  I've updated the profile above to show that most time is now in thir_body instead.